# setState not triggering re-render in React

Tags: reactjs, object, state, setstate, rerender

Full component:

```
const Column = ({ form, setForm, fieldset, blocks, selectedFieldsetId, setFieldBeingEdited }) => {
  //Sends block being edited to App component
  const editField = (e) => {
    const blockId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-blockid')
    const data = form.blocks[blockId]
    setFieldBeingEdited({ active: true, data })
  }

  const deleteBlock = (e) => {
    const blockId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-blockid')
    const updatedForm = { ...form }
    delete updatedForm.blocks[blockId]

    for (const fieldset in updatedForm.fieldsets) {
      for (let i = 0; i < updatedForm.fieldsets[fieldset].blockIds.length; i++) {
        if (updatedForm.fieldsets[fieldset].blockIds[i] === blockId) {
          updatedForm.fieldsets[fieldset].blockIds.splice(i, 1)
          return
        }
      }
    }
    setForm(updatedForm)
  }

  return <BlockList fieldset={fieldset} blocks={blocks} selectedFieldsetId={selectedFieldsetId} editField={editField} deleteBlock={deleteBlock} />
}
```

I have an object stored in state, but one of my setState calls is not triggering a re render immediately; I have to force some other state change through some other interaction on the page, and only then will the latest state be reflected.

As you can see I'm making a copy of the state object before I make changes to it, and calling setState (setForm) with the new object which has the changes made to it. Is anyone able to tell me where I'm going wrong? Thank you.

In case it's relevant at all, here is the data structure:

```
const initialData = {
  blocks: {},
  fieldsets: {
    [initialFieldsetId]: {
      id: initialFieldsetId,
      blockIds: [],
    },
  },
  fieldsetOrder: [initialFieldsetId],
}
```

Comment: Please show the full component

Answer (score 0):

have you tried creating state separately, as in

```
const [form, setForm] = useState();
```

This should work

Comment: I've declared state with `const [form, setForm] = useState(initialData)` in the App component, and passing down form as a prop

Comment: Aha I see, may I see the way you passed it on the other side as a prop? How did you define the component please?

Comment: FormHtml returns {html}.
`const html = form.fieldsetOrder.map((fieldsetId) => {
    const fieldset = form.fieldsets[fieldsetId]
    const blocks = fieldset.blockIds.map((blockId) => form.blocks[blockId])
    return (
      <Column
        key={fieldset.id}
        form={form}
        setForm={setForm}
        fieldset={fieldset}
        blocks={blocks}
        selectedFieldsetId={selectedFieldsetId}
        setFieldBeingEdited={setFieldBeingEdited}
      />
    )
    // return renderHtml(blocks, editField, deleteField, selectedFieldsetId)
  })`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I did it, but now solved (triggers re-render immediately).

New deleteBlock function:

```
const deleteBlock = (e) => {
    const fieldsetId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-fieldsetid')
    const blockId = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-blockid')
    const updatedForm = { ...form }
    const index = updatedForm.fieldsets[fieldsetId].blockIds.findIndex((el) => el === blockId)

    updatedForm.fieldsets[fieldsetId].blockIds.splice(index, 1)
    delete updatedForm.blocks[blockId]
    setForm(updatedForm)
  }
```

Still not sure exactly what was wrong with previous code, but at least it's working now.
I also realise my component structure is a little messy. Just integrating a new library I've never used before so will refactor that after I get it working. Thank you to those who took the time to have a look for me!

Comment: The issue was that you were updating the same `Form` object and React does not detect changes in nested fields of an object. With the new solution you create a new object (`updatedForm`), so React is able to pick-up that an update was indeed performed

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I don't understand how I was trying to update the same Form object in my original code. I created updatedForm before making my changes. Could you please explain?

Comment: Don't you simply return out of the function before reaching the `setState` line.